# Via terminal, find help/manual of a particular PHP function

Tags: php, manual

Let's say I want to learn about what "str_replace" does.

I could look online via the php.net documentation website, but I was wondering if I could also do it via the terminal/shell.

Maybe something like:

```
php -manual str_replace
```

It would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
php --rf <function>
```

is what you want to use.

> --rf <name> - Show information about function <name>.